# Is there an antonym for "trajectory"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Trajectory is defined as:

> the path followed by a projectile flying or an object moving under the action of given forces.

In game or software development, it's very common to visualize trajectory. Think of a satellite in a physics game or perhaps a billiards shot line. However, once the pool ball comes to rest, if I wanted to visualize the path it took to get there, what would I call that? Is there a scientific term similar to trajectory, or is "trail" or "path" the best I have?

Comment: You call it the trajectory. It's the same path whether it's being followed or retrieved from history.

Comment: You can use the same word (as it is still "the path followed by a projectile"), but in games it's often simply called 'path'.

Comment: I understand that *technically* trajectory is correct, but if I showed 100 people this picture and asked them to draw a line representing the trajectory of the vehicle, don't you think the vast majority would draw a line predicting where the vehicle would go and not where it has been? And how do you differentiate the two? Is "Past Trajectory" valid?  https://imgur.com/JFXDiHY

Comment: You could use 'positional history', but that would probably put more people off than the best choice ('trajectory', as has been said). // [bg.copernicus.org/articles](https://bg.copernicus.org/articles/4/759/2007/bg-4-759-2007-supplement.pdf) uses '7 day back trajectories' etc, but I think '7 day back' is used as a single compound premodifier (so **not** 'back trajectories').

Comment: If the game models something that has traditionally been telemetered, you could just call it *telemetry data*, but that works better for vehicles than for pool balls. Clearly, using *telemetry* within a game is purely metaphorical. It's only redeeming factor is that it does let you make the distinction you want to make.

Comment: Antonym means opposite in meaning.